# how connect to Azure Machine Learning Web service using PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-powershell, azure-machine-learning-service

To use Azure Machine Learning Web service [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/studio/consume-web-services) you can find some sample code in C#, R, Python and JavaScript. I want to use it in PowerShell.
I found [this](https://www.sepago.com/blog/2015/11/30/zugriff-mit-powershell-auf-azure-machine-learning-api-azureml) tutorial, but when I am running bellow line of code, it will return error that it is not recognized:

```
Set-AzureMLWebServiceConnection -URI $Url -APIKey $API_key

Output:
Set-AzureMLWebServiceConnection : The term 'Set-AzureMLWebServiceConnection' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable 
program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At C:\Users\Reza\Desktop\ndbench\Azure\Automation\01_get_metrics\add_target_to_tables - runbook_01.ps1:33 char:1
+ Set-AzureMLWebServiceConnection -URI $Url -APIKey $API_key
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Set-AzureMLWebServiceConnection:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

I can't found `Set-AzureMLWebServiceConnection` in my PowerShell command-list and I don't know how I can enable/install it.
[image]
Can you please guide me, how I can connect to Azure Machine Learning Web service using PowerShell?

Comment: Follow the installation instructions here: https://github.com/hning86/azuremlps/blob/master/README.md

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comment @gvee mentioned may be the best to use going forward though it is in beta.

However, to answer your question, use the `Install-Module -Name AzureML` [command](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/AzureML/1.0.1) to get access to the Azure ML commands.

[image]